# MarkDown Rendering bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

The markdown `![[image][1]][1]` renders a broken tag:

[[image http://google.com](http://google.com)][1](http://google.com)

Comment: You're trying to make an image that has URL syntax as a tooltip? If you want to make an image that links, you want the `!` inside like `[![image][1]][2]`. Still doesn't change that there is a broken HTML tag, though...

Comment: @Grace: I know.  I discovered this by accident.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106811/115866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do makes sense.. even a little.

Have a peek:

http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=%21%5B%5Bimage%5D%5B1%5D%5D%5B1%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5B1%5D%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

This is well into WTF? territory.

Instead I suggest something more sane:

```
![https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1f8A.png][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1f8A.png
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1f8A.png]

Comment: I realize that this is invalid syntax.  However, it's also a bug; it shouldn't emit a broken tag.

Comment: I haven't analysed this for XSS holes yet.

Comment: @SLaks: There shouldn't be one. You can produce the identical output by just writing `image">` yourself instead of using this syntax to produce it.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Jeff that this doesn't make much sense to try, it *does* behave somewhat nicely these days. It picks an absolutely valid interpretation of `![[image][1]][1]`, namely this:

```
![              // begin of the image
    [image      // the image's alt text is "[image"
]               // end of the alt text
[1]             // the image url (a reference, so it'll be google.com,
                // which isn't an image and thus looks broken)
]               // a verbatim "]"
[1]             // a shortlink with the link text "1" to the url referenced by [1],
                // which is google.com
```

It looks like this:

[[image http://google.com](http://google.com)][1](http://google.com)

In particular, there's no broken tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Confirmed**

[image: [image]

```
![[image](http://www.vightel.com/rw_common/themes/blendit/images/header/image4.jpg)](http://www.vightel.com/)
```

I'm assuming you're trying to wrap an image in a link.

And there is an interesting difference between the preview and actual rendering:

[image]