# Broken markdown when trying to make image clickable

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown

Markdown is probably broken. When I try to submit question/answer with

```
[![](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php)][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

it doesn't work, but when I write it with the classic parentheses, it works perfectly:

```
[![](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php)](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

**Proof:**

- First

[[](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php) http://stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)

- Second

[http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php](http://stackoverflow.com)

The first one is shown wrongly, after submission and while previewing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is getting into an area where Markdown's ambiguities and lenience aren't fixable, because by removing one edge case, you're creating two others. Since this isn't a particularly exciting issue, I'll leave it be; there are enough ways to accomplish what you're trying (related: [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link)), and the new problems that would be introduced by a fix are probably worse than what you have now.

One thing I'm changing though (next build), is the particular *way* in which this breaks, so it stops creating broken HTML (which then gets eaten by the sanitizer).

After this change, the created HTML still isn't what you expect, but it's a) valid, and b) it makes clear what happens here:

```
[![](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php)][1]
```

is understood like this:

```
[              just an open bracket; regular text
![             start of an image
    ...        the image alt text
]              the end of the alt text
[1]            the reference to the image link
```

so what you're getting in the generated HTML is this (line breaks inserted for clarification):

```
[<img
      src="http://stackoverflow.com"
      alt="](http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php)"
 >
```

Comment: Will be my question corrected in next build or should be there dummy edit? (is preview converted from markdown in realtime or is it static?)

Comment: The *preview* is obviously generated in realtime; the displayed post is only re-rendered when submitting an edit.

Comment: I have meant, if post, as I can see now, will be automatical fixed, corrected or should I edit it? From your comment, I assume I should edit that

Comment: This was basically what we were talking about in chat the other day. While I certainly trust you more than myself, I don't immediately see what new edge cases would be created by [applying the nested brackets pattern](https://code.google.com/r/tmslft-markdownsharp/source/detail?r=0d6bf22a1617b8a7c95dce2112eceae6cb2860c4) that the anchor regexes already use. The way things are now, even the `![alt](img) some text [link][ref]` case breaks.

Answer (score 3):

It works, if you use the following Markdown:

```
[![screenshot][2]][1]


 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com
 [2]: http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php
```

[screenshot http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Isn't it still a bug though?

Answer (score 0):

there is another way you can do,

```
[ ![1][2]][2]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com
[2]: http://phpcode.eu/images/1316518785.php
```